# Convert raw string to array

Tags: javascript, json

I need to convert raw String to json array in javascript below the my logic

Original:

`"[template1,template2]";`

Exception:

```
"["template1","template2"]";
```

Comment: Did you try out something? If yes, please post that code

Answer (score 1):

use `slice` to retrieve the text between the square brackets and then use `split`.

```js
const input = "[template1,template2]";

const arr = input.slice(1, -1).split(',');
console.log(arr);
```